# The value of the 'dependencies' field is expected to be a map in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

i recently started learning the dart language. I created new project and setting the path to dart-sdk but i got the error that, " The value of the 'dependencies' field is expected to be a map ". can anyone help me out here

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely the cause of formatting a error in your `pubspec.yaml`.

The dependencies should be formatted in this fashion:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

The "tabs" should 2 spaces. Tabs are not allowed according to the specifications of yaml.